# How to draw a sierpinski carpet in python using turtle

Tags: python, recursion, graphics, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create the Sierpinski carpet in python using turtle. This is my code so far:

```
from turtle import *

# Make a screen and a pen
pen = Pen()
screen = Screen()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color('orange')
pen.width(1.5)

def s (n, l):
    for i in range (4):
        s(n-1, l)
        pen.right(45); pen.forward(l); pen.right(45)
        s(n-1, l)
        pen.left(90); forward (l); pen.left(90)
        s(n-1, l)
        pen.right(45); pen.forward(l); pen.left(45)
        s(n-1, l)
```

However whenever I run it I get this message:

```
line 17, in s
    s(n-1, l)
  [Previous line repeated 990 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I tried using `if i in range(4):` but this does not work either, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is your question "I don't understand the term recursion depth/want to know, how to increase the maximum recursion depth" or "How can I improve my algorithm to prevent this"? For the first question, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it#3323013)

Comment: how do you start it ? `s(100, 10)` ? then try first `s(3, 10)`

Comment: I forgot "stop condition". It never stop executing next `s(n-1, l)` so it repeats it even for `n < 0`

Comment: I guess How can I improve my algorithm to prevent this, when run its meant to create a [sierpinski carpet](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/carpet/ifs10000000.gif)

Comment: what is variable `d` ? you use it in `forward(d)` but you don't assign value first.

Comment: first you have to add `"stop condition"` - you can't run next `s(n-1, l)` again and again. Because you get `s(-1, l)` and late `s(-10, l)` and `s(-100, l)` , etc.

Comment: oh shit sorry, didnt notice that, will change now, where do i put in stop condition?

Comment: I would put `"stop condition"` at the beginning of function `s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need "stop condition" to stop recursion.

For example:

```
 if n == 0: # "stop condition"

    # draw or exit

 else: # recursions

    # execute some recursions
```

---

I don't know algorithm but I created carpet with this code.

I use `trace(0)` and `update()` only to draw it much faster.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import turtle

# --- functions ---

def s(n, l):

    if n == 0: # stop conditions

        # draw filled rectangle

        turtle.color('black')
        turtle.begin_fill()
        for _ in range (4):
            turtle.forward(l)
            turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()

    else: # recursion

        # around center point create 8 smalles rectangles.
        # create two rectangles on every side 
        # so you have to repeat it four times

        for _ in range(4):
            # first rectangle
            s(n-1, l/3)    
            turtle.forward(l/3)

            # second rectangle
            s(n-1, l/3)    
            turtle.forward(l/3)

            # go to next corner
            turtle.forward(l/3)
            turtle.left(90)

        # update screen
        turtle.update()

# --- main ---    

# stop updating screen (to make it faster)
turtle.tracer(0) 

# start
s(4, 400)

# event loop
turtle.done()
```

---

### [image]

Wikipedia: [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet)